# Windows http parser

Tags: c++, http, openssl

Is there a C++ lib to parse a Http request.
With OpenSSL, SSL_read just fill-up a buffer that I would like to parse as a HTTP request/response.

So if you know a lib in C++/C that can do the job I would really appreciate
Thanks.

Comment: Have you thought about using .NET?

Comment: Perhaps [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) provides something. You should check for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try 
[POCO](http://pocoproject.org/documentation/index.html)?